# Does adding "files/" also exclude "backups/files/"?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the following directory structure:

```
backups
|_files
files
```

I need to exclude the top-level `files/` directory but keep `backups/files/` in the repo.

In my gitignore I have:

```
files/
```

This excludes the top-level `files/` directory but seems to also exclude the `files/` directory inside the `backups/` directory as well.

---

#### Question:

How do I exclude the top-level `files/` directory but keep `backups/files/` in the repo?

Sorry if this is easy - I've spent a scary amount of time trying to figure this out so am obviously missing something basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a leading slash to mean only the top-level /files/ dir:

```
/files/
```